# jQuery mobile header and footer hidden in Android Webview

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-webview

I've got the following problem that my with jQuery mobile ( 1.2.0 ) created header and footer are hidden on loading the document. 
If I click on any position the containers are showed prompt.

Other contents are always showed.

This bug only appers on my LG Optimus L5 ( Android 4.0.3 ).
On my Galaxy S3 ( 4.1 ), Galaxy Note ( 4.1 ) or any virtual machine ( 2.3.3, 4.2 ) or in the Browser ( PC ), there's no bug like this.

The HTML file is loaded into a WebView.

Here's my HTML source:

```html
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-iscroll="enable" data-fullscreen="false" id="header_app"> 
    <img src="logo.png" alt="" height="50" style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 0;" />
</div> 

<div data-role="content" id="cnt" > 
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-fullscreen="false"> 
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-iconpos="notext" id="bck" class="ui-btn-active"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" id="info"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" id="options"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="notext" id="refresh_data"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="myapp-email" data-iconpos="notext" id="msgs"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please excuse my bad english, I hope you can solve my problem.

Comment: Don't see a problem just looking over the code. Testing with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bECQe/ Could you be more specific in regards to which browser you are using on the device, Dolphin, Chrome, FireFox?

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior as well.  HTC Incredible 2, and SGIII

Answer (score 1):

If you have written

```
.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

in your css then just delete it. It may help you.